# TFS Changeset map to module

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs-2015, changeset

We are planning to categorize our project into different modules and each module will have its files linked to that. 
Lets say Modules are structured as below and we call it as Module1 and Module2 and let be there 100 of such modules.

```
Module1 
  Views\Mod1.html
  Controllers\Mod1Ctrl.vb
Module2
  Views\Mod2.html
  Controllers\Mod2Ctrl.vb
```

Once I make changes to files from many modules and make a check in- , from the changeset would I be able to get the modules to which the check in has been done.
It should be like once I give the changeset, I need to get the module list like Module1 ,Module 5 ...like that.

Is there any built in option in TFS 2015 to do that ?Is the labels for the same thing

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's the build system are you using? The new VNext  build or the old XAML build?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't any built in option to configure this. The "Label" is used to take a snapshot of your files.

> Labels let you take a snapshot of your files so that at a later date
>   you can refer back to that snapshot. By using your label, you can
>   view, build, or even roll back a large set of files to the state they
>   were in when you applied the label.